# How to sort this array in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following task description: Using an array, `shopping_list`, write the code to print the following words in sorted order: "potato", "cucumber", "banana", "persimmon".

Here is what I tried:

```
shopping_list = ["potato", "cucumber", "banana", "persimmon"]
shopping_list.sort
puts shopping_list
```

Why is this being marked incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `shopping_list.sort!`. Adding the exclamation at the end will save the existing array with those sorted values. When you print them again, it should be displayed sorted.

You can read more in the Ruby docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21.

Comment: The `sort` method returns a copy, which in the original code is thrown away. This might be confusing for people used to languages where it sorts in-place.

Comment: ...but it's better to write `puts shopping_list.sort` (unless there is an explicit requirement to also modify `shopping_list`).

Comment: _adding the exclamation at the end_ you're making it sound like `!` is an operator.

Comment: This is a good suggestion for the OP's issue, but is does not answer the OP's question.